# Options for "AutoMapping" from a DTO / Domain Entity with protected properties to "View Model" with public properties in PHP 5.x

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, automapper

Looking for "AutoMapper"-like feature/framework/pattern for taking data from a Doctrine 2 domain entity / DTO and mapping the protected properties on that entity to matching public properties on a View Model.

`$userEntity = $this-em->find(User::class, 1);`

`$userViewModel = AutoMapper->Map($userEntity, new UserViewModel());`

Where the only significant difference between `User` and `UserViewModel` is that `User` contains get/set accessors with protected backing fields (per doctrine's instructions), whereas `UserViewModel` contains public properties that match in name [a subset of] the protected backing fields on `User`.

An thoughts on how to accomplish this? (preferably without reflection)

Note that the domain entity has public get accessor, so the solution can leverage those accessors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with my own crude, yet effective, bare-bones implementation of AutoMapper for PHP to solve this problem for me.  This method will map from public properties or public getters (convention based naming) to public properties on the target entity.

Hope this helps someone out:

```
class Mapper
{
    /**
     * This method will attempt to source all public property values on $target from $source.
     *
     * By convention, it'll look for properties on source with the same name,
     * .. and will fallback camel-cased get/set accessors to use.
     *
     * Note that underscores in properties will be translated to capital letters in camel-cased getters.
     *
     * @param $source object
     * @param $target object
     * @return object
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static function Map($source, $target)
    {
        $targetProperties = get_object_vars($target);
        $sourceProperties = get_object_vars($source);

        foreach ($targetProperties as $name => $value)
        {
            //
            // match properties
            //

            $matchingSourcePropertyExists = array_key_exists($name, $sourceProperties);
            if ($matchingSourcePropertyExists)
            {
                $target->{$name} = $source->{$name};
                continue;
            }

            //
            // fall back on matching by convention-based get accessors
            //

            $sourceMethods = get_class_methods(get_class($source));
            $getterName = "get" . self::convertToPascalCase($name);
            $matchingGetAccessorExists = in_array($getterName, $sourceMethods);
            if ($matchingGetAccessorExists)
            {
                $target->{$name} = $source->{$getterName}();
                continue;
            }

            //
            // if we ever fail to map an entity on the target, throw
            //

            $className = get_class($target);
            throw new Exception("Could not auto-map property $name on $className.");
        }

        return $target;
    }

    /**
     * Converts this_kind_of_string into ThisKindOfString.
     * @param $value string
     * @return string
     */
    private static function convertToPascalCase($value)
    {
        $value[0] = strtoupper($value[0]);

        $func = create_function('$c', 'return strtoupper($c[1]);');

        return preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', $func, $value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My implementation of automapping using Symfony's components

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\ApiResource\Utils;

use Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccess;
use Symfony\Component\PropertyInfo\Extractor\ReflectionExtractor;

class GenericMapper
{
    public static function map(object $source, object $target): void
    {
        $reflectionExtractor = new ReflectionExtractor();
        $sourceProperties = $reflectionExtractor->getProperties($source::class);
        $propertyAccessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

        foreach ($sourceProperties as $propertyName) {
            if ($propertyAccessor->isWritable($target, $propertyName) && $propertyAccessor->isReadable($source, $propertyName)) {
                $propertyAccessor->setValue($target, $propertyName, $propertyAccessor->getValue($source, $propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```